# set to NULL if the string is empty or if there are spaces, tabs

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, case

I am a beginner and I'm looking to set my fields (first_name, last_name, country) to NULL if they have a "backspace" or "tab" character sequence in SQL. any leads please?

Comment: I would recommend **not** to use NULL in this case, but an empty string. The meaning is quite different, and it will makes your statements simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
select
    case when first_name !~ '^\s*$' then first_name end as first_name,
    case when last_name  !~ '^\s*$' then last_name  end as last_name,
    case when country    !~ '^\s*$' then country    end as country 
from mytable
```

Regex `^\s*$` matches on a string composed of 0 to N space characters. `\s` typically stands for a spaces, tabs, and different types of line breaks (carriage returns, line feeds, ...).

Comment: is there another solution without regex pls ?

Comment: @kevin13: why? This does look like the simpler approach for your problem.

Comment: it's the simplest but is there any other sulution without regex to optimize my request

Answer (score 0):

> if they have a "backspace" or "tab" character sequence

Postgres has specific support for such special characters using [escape strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) and particular escape sequences.

If you specifically want to match on backspaces and tabs, then the simplest method is a regular expression:

```
str ~ E'[\b\t]'
```

The SQL is:

```
select (case when first_name !~ E'[\b\t]' then first_name end) as first_name,
       (case when last_name !~ E'[\b\t]' then last_name end) as last_name,
       (case when country !~ E'[\b\t]' then country end) as country 
from t;
```

You can express this using `like` and `and`:

```
select (case when first_name not like E'%\b%' and first_name not like E'%\t%' then first_name end) as first_name,
       (case when last_name not like E'%\b%' and last_name  not like E'%\t%' then last_name end) as last_name,
       (case when country not like E'%\b%' and country  not like E'%\t%' then country end) as country 
from t
```

But the regular expression is really simpler.

Comment: my question is : if (first_name,last_name,country) have "spacial characters or backspaces or tabs" then edite (first_name,last_name,country)=NULL

Comment: @kevin13 . . . That is in the title, but not in the question (as quoted in this answer).  You can obviously extend the regular expression with any characters that you want to exclude.  You seem to have a specific list in mind.